# rewrite request for /folder to folder/index.php without 301 redirect with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I put an index.php in `/pipe/index.php`

I'd like to rewrite (internal, not redirect)
`https://host/pipe?token=abc` to `https://host/pipe/index.php?token=abc`

what I tried (caveat, assumes there is always a ? in the url):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^([^?]*)(.*)$" "$1/$2" [PT]
```

my hope was to split at the ? and just insert a / there.

But it seems apache finds out that "oh, pipe is a folder" *before* checking my .htacces (?) Because despite my [PT] it still *redirects* with 301 to `/pipe/?token=abc`, when I hoped for internal rewrite.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to create a generic `/<anything>?<query-string>` to `/<anything>/index.php?<query-string>`? Where `<anything>` is a single path segment? Or literally any URL-path? What if the target does not exist?

Comment: `mod_dir` module automatically adds a trailing `/` after real directories  and causes a 301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it seems apache finds out that "oh, pipe is a folder" before checking my .htacces (?)

Yes, mod_dir will append the trailing slash with a 301 redirect. Although this occurs *after* mod_rewrite has processed the URL (if indeed it is being processed at all - *see below*). (The `PT` flag is irrelevant in `.htaccess`, since the resulting rewrite is passed through as a URL-path by default.)

> ```
> RewriteRule "^([^?]*)(.*)$" "$1/$2" [PT]
> ```

However, your existing rule (by itself) would result in a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error) since it matches itself and repeatedly appends a slash. If you are seeing a 301 redirect as mentioned above then either this rule is not doing anything (are `.htaccess` overrides enabled?) or you have a conflict with other rules.

As you've stated, this rule also assumes that the query string (with leading `?`) is also matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. `$2` in the above rule is therefore always empty (unless you have `%3F` in the URL-path, ie. a %-encoded `?`).

The query string is contained in its own variable, `QUERY_STRING`. But you simply want to pass through the same query string, so you don't need to do anything special here, since that happens by default.

---

#### Solution

To prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash, you need to set `DirectorySlash Off` at the top of the *root* `.htaccess` file.

> Note that these directives must go in the `.htaccess` file in the root/parent directory, as opposed to the subdirectory that has the trailing slash omitted. This is because the mod_rewrite directives (that "fix" the URL by appending the trailing slash) would never actually be processed in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file. The trailing slash would seem to be required for mod_rewrite to function. (However, the mod_dir `DirectorySlash Off` directive would still be processed successfully, so the slash would not be appended.)

For example:

```
# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

# Must disable directory listings when "DirectorySlash Off" is set
Options -Indexes
```

However, you need to then manually append the trailing slash to any directory, where it is omitted, with an internal rewrite to "fix" the URL (and to correctly serve the `DirectoryIndex` document, ie. `index.php`).

```
# Ensure DirectoryIndex is set correctly
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Append trailing slash to any directory where it has been omitted
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [L]
```

The trailing slash on the directory (via the internal rewrite) is required in order to serve the `DirectoryIndex` document, otherwise, you get a 403 Forbidden, even if the `DirectoryIndex` document is present.

If the trailing slash is omitted and directory listings (mod_autoindex) are enabled (disabled above) then a directory listing would be generated even if a `DirectoryIndex` document is present in that directory. (Which is why directory listings must be disabled when `DirectorySlash Off` is set.)

NB: You will need to make sure the browser cache is cleared since the earlier 301 redirect by mod_dir to append the trailing slash will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Great! Thank you for pointing out the DirectorySlash directive. Only caveat I found was that the .htaccess must be placed in `https://host/` to match the "filename" -d (check if is directory I guess). I had placed it in the `https://host/pipe/` dir :P

Comment: @ArnoTeigseth Yes, the `.htaccess` file must be placed in the root directory (I've updated my answer to clarify this), but not for the reason you mention. Without the slash on the directory, the mod_rewrite directives in the `.htaccess` file in that directory are not actually processed at all! So it doesn't even get as far as checking whether the request maps to a directory or not (although the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ as written wouldn't match anyway).

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pipe/?$ /pipe/index.php [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` flag is actually redundant here, it is the default, but it makes things clearer if you compare it to that variant (both work):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pipe/?$ /pipe/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD,L]
```

The documentation of the [rewriting module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), more specific of the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive clearly points out that the query string is *not* part of the path the rule's pattern is matched against.

If you want to have more control about the content of the query string you can use a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?pipe/?$ /pipe/index.php?token=%1 [QSD,L]
```

Also you might want to redirect the original URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?pipe/index.php /pipe [QSA,R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?pipe/?$ /pipe/index.php [QSA,L]
```

And finally you might also want to take a look at the [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive which might offer a solution without any rewriting at all, though this depends a bit on your setup ...